# multiple step math equations python

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter two numbers and then have the system figure out the sum, difference, product and quotient of the given numbers and print the results out. This is what I have so far. When I ran the code for sum it came back correct, when I added the difference function it doesn't work.

```
def total_sum(num1,num2):
result = num1 + num2
return result

def total_difference(num_1,num_2):
    result = num_1 - num_2
    return result

def total_product(number1,number2):
    result = number1 * number2
    return result

def total_quotient (number_1,number_2):
    result = number_1 / number_2
    return result

def main ():
   value_1 = float(input('Enter a number :'))
   value_2 = float(input('Enter second number :'))
   value_2 != 0

   add = total_sum(value_1,value_2)
   difference = total_difference(value_1, value_2)
   product = total_product(value_1,value_2)
   quotient = total_quotient(value_1,value_2)

   print ('The total is {:.1f}'.format(add))
   print ('The difference is {:.1f}'.format(difference))
   print ('The product is {:.2f}' .format(product))
   print ('The quotient is {:.2f}'.format(quotient))

main()
```

Comment: Did you forget a single quote in the second print in main()?

Comment: @AndrewL I'm very new to python, i'm not sure where you are talking about. its giving me a syntax error on the "def" part of the def total_sum

Comment: `print ('The difference is',format(total_difference, '.1f))` this is the line Andrew is talking about. Was it a typo when posting the code ?

Comment: No, I want it to print the answer for sum, difference, product, and quotient of the users input. @SilentMonk

Comment: You have missed a single quote, the line should have been - `print ('The difference is',format(total_difference, '.1f'))`. Please do this change and try.

Comment: @SilentMonk Flagged as a typographical error, you should too :)

Comment: Corrected, when I run it again it is giving me this error 'float' object is not iterable@SilentMonk

Comment: @CzSzPzTz, please edit the question. Otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to cause any issue for now, but future note: functions can be used like variables, so by doing `total_sum = sum(value_1,value_2)`, you essentially have redefined the `def total_sum` function within `main`. To not do this, pick a non conflicting variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few mistakes,

1. You missed the `'` as pointed out in comments by Andrew.
2. You made a mistake in the `.format`.
3. You had used `results` in your difference function where you were returning result.

Here's the corrected code:

```
def total_sum(num1,num2):
    result = num1 + num2
    return result

def total_difference(num_1,num_2):
    result = num_1 - num_2
    return result

def main ():
    value_1 = float(input('Enter a number :'))
    value_2 = float(input('Enter second number :'))

    add = total_sum(value_1,value_2)
    difference = total_difference(value_1, value_2)

    print ('The total is {:.5f}'.format(add))
    print ('The difference is {:.5f}'.format(difference))


main()
```

Comment: thank you! So I would just add the quotient and the product steps in the same order correct? @Ani Menon

Comment: the OP choose to use the builtin `format` function instead of `str.format` specifying the spec inside the string itself, I don't think that counts as a mistake.

Comment: @CzSzPzTz Yes. (and don't forget to add `value_2` not equal to zero in the division operator)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use the sum method which must iterate through a list, you are trying to do this with a tuple.

you have the equivalent of:

```
a = sum(1,2)
print(a)
```

which will return `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

instead you should add your entered values to a list as follows:

```
list2sum = []
list2sum.append(value_1) # do the same for 2)
a = sum(list2sum)
print(a)
```

for [more on sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

> sum(iterable[, start])
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from
>   left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The
>   iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not
>   allowed to be a string.
>
> For some use cases, there are good alternatives to sum(). The
>   preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling
>   ''.join(sequence). To add floating point values with extended
>   precision, see math.fsum(). To concatenate a series of iterables,
>   consider using itertools.chain().

IF you are trying to use your total sum function, do so by using it appropriately:

```
a = total_sum(value_1, value_2)
print(a)   #print to confirm result
```

Remember, sum is actually a built-in-function, as mentioned above. I do not know why you are trying to use it here:

```
 total_sum = sum(value_1,value_2)
```

Comment: I believe the total_sum method was meant to be used in place of sum there, in any case, good for the documentation reference